# Angular 2 component model refresh view without model changes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I have an Angular 2.4.0 application I'm working on with a form that has some backing Javascript validating/formatting a couple of the fields. When the formatting of the fields completes, the view does not update if the value returned from the formatting matches the original value attached to the model. Is there a way to force the view to update? Since there isn't a model change, forcing a component refresh hasn't had any effect. I'm guessing I'll need to update the view separately with something like jQuery, but I wanted to check if there was a better solution first.

**Component:**
    export class Component {
      field: string

```
  formatField(updatedField: string) {
    this.field = updatedField.replace(new Regexp("[^\\d]", "g"), ""); // remove everything except numbers
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="field" (ngModelChange)="formatField($event)">
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above example, if the model is "1", then I enter `"1;['];["`, and `formatField` returns `"1"`, the screen will still display `"1;['];["` when I'm expecting `"1"` to display instead (which is the returned value of the `formatField` call).

**Edit:** fixed `ngModelUpdate` to `ngModelChange` in example (typo). Added Angular 2 version to description.

Comment: What version of Angular 2 are you using ? Try to change `ngModelUpdate` by `ngModelChange`

Comment: My mistake, I put ngModelUpdate in the example instead of ngModelChange. I am using ngModelChange in Angular 2.4.0 to call that format method, but the view still doesn't update if the model value hasn't changed.

Comment: ok, I see. You can try to bind your function to keyup event, something like : `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field" (keyup)="formatField(field)">`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To refresh the view you need to explicitly run the change detector after you make a change to the model, then you can modify the model and `ngModel` will update the value.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

formatField(updatedField: string) {
    this.field = updatedField;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.field = updatedField.replace(new RegExp("[^\\d]", "g"), ""); // remove everything except numbers
}
```

Comment: Dirty hack but it's works. Any other option just to rerender input view?