# Subscribe to "after view change" when using [ngClass] in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have the following html element, where the class changes depending on the value of `isToolbarCompact`, which just changes its width.
Now when I call `toggleToolbarCompact()` the Angular change detection changes the view. But this is happening asynchronously. I want to run some code after calling `toggleToolbarCompact()`, for which the view has to be already changed.

Is there a way to 'subscribe' to the updated view and run my code then? Or maybe an other way to achieve that?
Thanks!

```js
toggleToolbarCompact() {
   this.isToolbarCompact = !this.isToolbarCompact;
  // code here is run before the view changed
}
```

```css
.toolbar-wide {
   width: 230px;
}

.toolbar-compact {
   width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sk-scroll-bar" [ngClass]="{'toolbar-wide':!isToolbarCompact, 'toolbar-compact': isToolbarCompact}"></div>
```

Comment: What kind of code is it that would need to wait for the view to be updated?

Comment: I think `setTimeout(()=> { // your code}, 0 );` will do the trick

Comment: `setTimeout()` does work. However I think the cleaner solution is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281059/angular-2-component-model-refresh-view-without-model-changes). Thanks everyone!

Comment: The Code that needs the view to be updated ist rezising a html canvas next to the toolbar, based on how much space there is. So the change in width of the toolsbar has to happen first.